# Multiple sequential abstract base classes in Python 3.4+

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

Take a common vehicle inheritance example where `Vehicle` and `Car` are ABCs and the latter inherits from the former.  We then have e.g. `FordMustang` which is not abstract and should inherit from `Car`.

So, we have

```
class Vehicle(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_vehicle_method(self):
        pass
```

Which is presumably all fine and dandy.  However, for the `Car` class, I am not sure whether it should inherit only from `Vehicle` or from `Vehicle` and `ABC`, and if so, in what order?  Moreover, I would like to force `abstract_vehicle_method()` to be defined in `FordMustang` and all such non-abstract classes, so should I repeat the `abstract_vehicle_method` definition in `Car` or will the inheritance sort this out?

To enumerate the options:

Should it be

```
class Car(Vehicle):
    [...]
```

or

```
class Car(ABC, Vehicle):
    [...]
```

or

```
class Car(Vehicle, ABC):
    [...]
```

and (assuming the first is correct for simplicity) should it be

```
class Vehicle(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_vehicle_method(self):
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):

    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_vehicle_method(self):
        pass

    # Some car specific defs here

class FordMustang(Car):

    def abstract_vehicle_method(self):
        # Concrete def here
```

or just

```
class Vehicle(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_vehicle_method(self):
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):

    # Some car specific defs here

class FordMustang(Car):

    def abstract_vehicle_method(self):
        # Concrete def here
```

Comment: It all depends what you want to do with those classes. Do you want Car to be an abstract class or do you want it to be used to instantiate objects?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: not to the answer to the question stated here, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly inherit from `Vehicle`; the metaclass that makes `Vehicle` 'abstract' is inherited along with it. You do not need to mix in `ABC` for those subclasses.

You also don't need to re-define the method. It is inherited too, along with it's 'abstractness'.

Under the hood, the metaclass tracks what attributes are 'abstract'; as long as there are any, the class can't be used to create instances. You can add more abstract methods, or by providing a different attribute for the same name, remove abstract methods from the set.

Demo for your specific example:

```
>>> from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
>>> class Vehicle(ABC):
...     @abstractmethod
...     def abstract_vehicle_method(self):
...         pass
...
>>> type(Vehicle)  # it's an abstract class
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
>>> Vehicle.__abstractmethods__  # this set determines what is still abstract
frozenset({'abstract_vehicle_method'})
>>> class Car(Vehicle):
...     pass
...
>>> type(Car)  # still an abstract class
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
>>> Car.__abstractmethods__  # still has abstract methods, incl. inherited methods
frozenset({'abstract_vehicle_method'})
>>> class FordMustang(Car):
...     def abstract_vehicle_method(self):
...         pass
...
>>> type(FordMustang)  # still an abstract class
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
>>> FordMustang.__abstractmethods__  # but with no abstract methods left
frozenset()
>>> FordMustang()  # so we can create an instance
<__main__.FordMustang object at 0x106054f98>
```

Comment: I am curious as to where the TypeError is raised from when instantiating an abstract class. It does not seem to come from anywhere in the abc module. Do you know what raises it?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: that's handled by `object.__new__`; see [the v3.7.0 implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/typeobject.c#L3671-L3714). The exception is raised for any class with `Py_TPFLAGS_IS_ABSTRACT` set. The flag is set when `__abstractmethods__` is set to a non-empty value, by `ABCMeta.__new__`.

Comment: Thanks.  What was throwing me was that PyCharm thinks this is 'wrong', despite it making sense and being the most elegant approach.  For me it gives a "Class Car must implement all abstract methods" code inspection error.  Perhaps I'll raise it as a ticket with them to fix, though actually I suppose there's no way for an IDE to tell the difference in intention and determine whether some inherited class is supposed to be abstract, or whether the user just forgot to implement the abstract methods in a non-abstract class.  Though it also triggers this error when I mixin `ABC`.  Go figure.

Comment: @P.Lau: that's definitely PyCharm making an assumption that you can't create a hierarchy of abstract classes from a base class, which is wrong.